# Showing Months and year as header through JTAppleCalendar

Tags: ios, swift, calendar, jtapplecalendar

I am using JTAppleCalendar in my iOS application but I am finding it difficult to implement headers that show the month and year at the top of the calendar as a conventional calendar normally would. I have followed instructions in the documentation but I am still finding it difficult despite managing to add 'headers' to show the days of the week albeit I feel maybe not correctly. For anyone who has implemented this library before, can I get some help how to do this? Or maybe another calendar you have used that has an easier way to accomplish this?

I want the screen to look a little like this:
[image]

While mine currently looks like this:
[image]

Documentation:
https://patchthecode.github.io/Headers/

I implement the days of the week as so:

```
    // This sets the height of your header
func calendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, sectionHeaderSizeFor range: (start: Date, end: Date), belongingTo month: Int) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 200, height: 50)
}
// This setups the display of your header
func calendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, willDisplaySectionHeader header: JTAppleHeaderView, range: (start: Date, end: Date), identifier: String) {
    let headerCell = (header as? PinkSectionHeaderView)
    headerCell?.title.text = "S           M           T           W           T           F           S"
}
```

Comment: Hi, before i answer your question, can you let me know this: Do you want your S|M|T|W|T|F|S header to scroll when you scroll the calendar? AND do you want to Month and Year Label to remain stationary when you scroll the calendar?

Comment: Hi, yes well i'm trying to make it scroll when you scroll and the days of the week to scroll with that particular month and the same for the month/year

Comment: I just posted an answer. But if you need more help you can always join [HERE](https://gitter.im/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you just made this a whole lot more difficult than it should be.

What you saw on the tutorial site was an example Of how you can setup a header with a simple UILabel on it called `title`. You do not have to follow this exactly if your calendar design is different. Simply design it however you wish.

It seems that what you want is not a UILabel. You want 7 labels; each representing a day of the week. The easiest way to do this is just to create 7 UILabels inside of a Horizontal Stackiew. StackView's spacing should be set to `full` and should be set to `fill equally`. Then all you have to do is click on the individual labels and set their alignment to Center.

[image]

Make the constraints of the StackView stretch to the ends of the headerView.
Done. Your S|M|T|W|T|F|S view is complete without hard coding the spaces; which is a bad thing to do.

Next it seems you want another 2 labels. One for the `Month`, and another for the `Year`. So create those labels in the header view, and then create the outletLets for them. Then you can properly set them up in the following function.

```
func calendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, willDisplaySectionHeader header: JTAppleHeaderView, range: (start: Date, end: Date), identifier: String) {
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Currently using version 7.0 of the JTAppleCalendar. Suppose I have a UILabel which is supposed to show the month. How do I set the month in this function? I am not well versed in swift

Comment: @patchthecode.com Great for the answer but currently this function is not available at the moment and I cannot achieve it as needed! Another help please!

Comment: @EKChhuon youre probably using older version. Check here https://patchthecode.com/jtapplecalendar-home/headers/

Comment: Many thank you for reply. Now I could solve the problem by using this function for outside Header instead.
`func calendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, didScrollToDateSegmentWith visibleDates: DateSegmentInfo) {
monthTitle.text = formatter.string(from: visibleDates.monthDates.first!.date)
}`

However, my header title does't change on first load until we scroll it back and forth. How can I solve this? @patchthecode.com

Comment: Did you download the sample app on that link i sent you? It is located at the bottom of the page. The Header correctly updates on first load. Can you use that as an example?